# What do you call a person who purportedly represents the best qualities of a nation?

Tags: phrase-requests

In Russian there is an expression "conscience of a nation" (совесть нации) which means a person who embodies best qualities of that nation (according to one's subjective opinion).

In the 1980s and 1990s this term was often applied to people like Sakharov and Solzhenitsyn. Today, depending on one's political views, one could say that Noam Chomsky, Ron Paul, Edward Snowden, Abby Martin, or Julian Assange are such people. Old (sometimes), wise men and women, moral giants.

**What would be an equivalent of "conscience of a nation" in American English?** (apart from *epitome* which seems too general)

Usage of the expression in a sentence:

> Ron Paul, ______, ran for president in 1988, 2008, and 2012.

Comment: The phrase that best fits that blank is "libertarian ideologue"

Comment: I don't know about Americans, but we Brits have ***national treasures*** - very specifically ***people*** (like Steven Fry, David Attenborough, Joanna Lumley,... who ***everyone*** approves of). But our national treasures are almost never "political" - at least half the country (usually more) hate just about any politician you could think of.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "National treasure" is excellent, thanks.

Comment: One-sided activists may think they represent the national conscience. Others might see them as self-important, elitist, lecturing. Like bragging I'm humble. Just saying.

Comment: The word that comes to my mind is [quintessential](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/quintessential), as in "_____ is the quintessential American."

Comment: I'm not a fan of jingoism, but in the U.S. context, "patriot" comes to mind.

Comment: *but we Brits have national treasures* - that's news to this Brit. If @FumbleFingers' comment were an answer I'd demand citations!

Comment: "Patriot" carries the wrong connotations. The likes of Chomsky and Solzhenitsyn are/were critics of their governments and state (going beyond the merely political); and as an extreme libertarian Paul sometimes came into that category too. You can argue that in some circumstances a patriot can hate the government, want to destroy the entire economy system, etc, but it's not a natural association. On the other hand ["national treasure"](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/this-britain/50-national-treasures-957884.html) is definitely a lot cosier/facile than "conscience of a nation".

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: I haven't actually looked for a "definition" as such, but after writing the first dozen words or so of my first comment, I did cut&paste "national treasures" into a google as an *aide-memoire* for some examples. Unfortunately I didn't cut&paste the ***names*** in the list that Google helpfully returned me as a banner of pictures for the first "result". So I won't be able to find any citations endorsing ***Steven** Fry* as one of them,...

Comment: ...but ["national treasure **Stephen Fry**"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22national+treasure+stephen+fry%22&oq=%22national+treasure+stephen+fry%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.436577j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets thousands of hits.

Comment: Maybe a *national archetype*?